# Apex Unit Testing List<Case>

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, unit-test

I have a method `public static List<Case> findCase (Id recordId)` that returns `List<Case> details`. I wrote the following Test and it passed.

```
List<Case> details  = HighlightComponentController.findCase('5002a000003Y1bYAAS');
System.AssertEquals(0,details.size());
```

This tells me that the method isn't returning the data it should be. When I add this component to a layout in the sandbox it works fine and the data is returned and bound. Please help.

Comment: Is this in a unit test, or just an execute anonymous script?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Understanding Test Data](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_data.htm) and specifically [Isolation of Test Data from Organization Data in Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_data_access.htm):

> Starting with Apex code saved using Salesforce API version 24.0 and later, test methods don’t have access by default to pre-existing data in the organization, such as standard objects, custom objects, and custom settings data, and can only access data that they create.

**You have to create your own test data.** A proper unit test setup cannot possibly work with a hard-coded Id. Basic structure of your test should look as follows:

```
@IsTest
static void testMyMethod()
{
    SObject record = someSetupMethod();
    // your setup method should insert to the database

    Test.startTest();
        List<Case> result = MyClass.myMethod(record.Id);
    Test.stopTest();

    system.assertEquals(new List<Case>(), result, 'Include an informative message here');
}
```

Please note that even if your test *would* work with a hard-coded Id in this org, it wouldn't work when you try to deploy elsewhere. **[Never, *ever* use hard-coded Ids in your code base](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices#Best_Practices_.2310:_Avoid_Hardcoding_IDs)**.